# Install Docker on Windows Server 2016 (server not connected to internet)

Tags: docker, docker-machine

Can we install docker on Windows Server 2016(not connected to internet)

Here is the reference from microsoft website (https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/virtualization/windowscontainers/quick-start/set-up-environment?tabs=Windows-Server)

```
Install-Module -Name DockerMsftProvider -Repository PSGallery -Force
Install-Package -Name docker -ProviderName DockerMsftProvider
```

Is there an offline version that we can download and install?

Comment: If your use case is strict enough to require offline installations, then may I ask why your organization requires Docker to be running on Windows?